# How to use external login provider with a custom user store?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 Web application that allows user to authenticate using an external provider.

In Internet there are a lot of information teaching how to enable external login providers, but none teaches how to actually authenticate the user in the system when login returns to the MVC site. All information I have found assumes developer is using the default ASP.NET identity user store, so it tells nothing about what to do next.

For example, in Google, when user selects the Google account, the call returns to the site and run the method `FindAsync` of the custom user store, but, after that, how can I actually log the user in?

This is one my attempts to retrieve the user e-mail:

```
    public Task<T> FindAsync(UserLoginInfo login)
    {
        var info = AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync().Result;
        var emailClaim = externalIdentity.Result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email);
    }
```

But `GetExternalLoginInfoAsync` does not belong to `AuthenticationManager` object.

I have read that `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin` should be included, but in my case, that NuGet package is already included, and of course, the corresponding `using` statement is present in the code.

Any help, please?

Comment: Does it mean you are not using net-identity?

Comment: Yes... .net identity with custom user store.  I have seen that the callback function in AccountController does contain the user e-mail and username coming from the external provider but it calls the Find method of SigningManager only with part of the information containing a provider key and provider name. That causes the Find method of custom user store to have a parameter I showed in the question . I can solve it by replacing the SigningManager method, but I think that is not the correct way to manage it.

Comment: does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

Comment: @jomsk1e That site does not show how to do it using custom user store, however, I have finally done something similar. That site is creating the user in ExternalLoginConfirmation method of AccountController. In my case, the requirement is that the user should already exist in the user store, so I am retrieving user in ExternalLoginCallback method, adding the login and finally signing him in.